# How to show radio buttons from panel in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to do, onclick of any radio button from `panel1`, show `panel2` radio buttons and according to `panel2` radio button selection display `panel3` options. On window load event hide `panel2` and `panel3`. only first event panel will displayed. I don't know where i am going wrong, please anybody can  help me.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById("right").style.display='none';
 document.getElementById("right1").style.display='none';
}

jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');
        
        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
function accordion()
{
  if(document.getElementById("select1").checked)
  {
    document.getElementById('right').style.display='block';
 document.getElementById('right1').style.display='none';
  }
}
```

```css
#left{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
 background-color: rgb(252, 203, 139);
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right{
/*position: relative;
float: left;*/
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 146px;
background-color: rgb(252, 203, 139);
height: 290px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 104px;
z-index: 1;
right: 1055px;
}

#right1{
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 146px;
background-color: rgb(252, 203, 139);
height: 290px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 215px;
z-index: 1;
right: 1000px;
}
div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" onclick="accordion()" name="select1" value="link1" />Option 1</a><br/>
 <a href="#target2" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" onclick="accordion()" name="select1" value="link2" />Option 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" onclick="accordion()" name="select1" value="link3" />Option 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right" >
  <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:rgb(130, 236, 130)">
 <a href="#target4" id="abc" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que1" />Que1</a><br />
 <a href="#target5" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que2" />Que2</a> <br /><br />
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:rgb(118, 249, 179)">
 <a href="#target6" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que3" />Que3</a><br />
 <a href="#target7" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que4" />Que4</a> <br /><br />
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:rgb(249, 222, 118)">
 <a href="#target8" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que5" />Que5</a><br />
 <a href="#target9" class="panel" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="radio" name="select" value="que6" />Que6</a> <br /><br />
  </div>
  
</div>

<div id="right1">
  <div class="panel" id="target4" style="background:rgb(189, 181, 189)">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link1" />Link1<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link2" />Link2<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link3" />Link3<br />
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="target5" style="background:rgb(130, 204, 236)">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link4" />Link4<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link5" />Link5<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link6" />Link6<br />
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="target6" style="background:rgb(189, 181, 189)">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link1" />Link1<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link2" />Link2<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link3" />Link3<br />
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="target7" style="background:rgb(130, 204, 236)">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link4" />Link4<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link5" />Link5<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link6" />Link6<br />
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="target8" style="background:rgb(189, 181, 189))">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link1" />Link1<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link2" />Link2<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link3" />Link3<br />
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="target9" style="background:rgb(130, 204, 236)">
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link4" />Link4<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link5" />Link5<br />
 <input type="radio" name="select2" value="link6" />Link6<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your code.

1. In half code you are using jquery code and some code in vanilla javascript(which is conceptually not wrong.) but you can write better code using jquery.
2. You are checking document.getElementById("select1").checked.
   but you don't have "select1" ID in your code. you have added name "select1"

if you make below change in your code, you can see your code running

```
function accordion() {
  if($("#left input[type=radio]:checked").length > 0){
    document.getElementById('right').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('right1').style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps